# Strange bug with hyperref, percent symbol and cyrillic character

Tags: xetex, hyperref, cyrillic

I minimized it to the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{\%н}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it:

```
xelatex test.tex
```

the first run compiles fine, but on the second run it complains:

```
Runaway argument?
{
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.3 \begin{document}
```

If I remove either `hyperref`, or percent sign, or cyrillic char, it compiles fine. I observe this behavior only on TeXLive 2012 distribution - 2009 distribution works just fine.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With that setting, the annotation written in the `.out` file is

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{%н}{}% 1
```

where the problem is self evident: the "naked" `%` ends the line.

You have two workarounds available:

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
```

that makes the following annotation

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{\376\377\000\045\004\075}{}% 1
```

thus avoiding the problem. The second workaround is

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

This seems better, because the `bookmark` package better manages bookmarks.

Comment: With the first workaround, I get `** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...`. Second workaround works fine, but is a bit strange - since I don't work with bookmarks, just with simple links.

Comment: @Rogach The warning can be safely ignored. If you don't need bookmarks, you can pass the option `bookmarks=false` to `hyperref` (they are enabled by default).

Comment: adding \usepackage{bookmark} helped me, thanks!